# Probability to hit a ball once in four tries with a 1/3 chance to hit

Tags: probability

**Suppose a baseball player gets a hit with the probability of 1/3 every time he steps to the plate. What is the probability the player gets exactly one hit in four tries?**

I apologize if this question has been asked before. I tried searching for one that helped, but I couldn't quite find anything. I'm awful with probabilities, so a detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is some useful information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial. Your problem has $4$ trials with success probability $\frac{1}{3}$, and you wish to find the probability of exactly $1$ successful trial.

Comment: Can you calculate the probability that the player will have a *hit* in the first trial and a *miss* in the subsequent three trials? It should be $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3$. Now, what is the probability to have a hit in the *second* trial and a miss in the other three? It should be the same as before: $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3$. The same will happen if you want the hit in the *third* trial, and again in the *fourth* trial. The total probability is the sum of those, i.e. $4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3=\frac{32}{81}$.